# How to handle Extension ID change in Chrome plugin?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

Scenario:
1. Old plugin built with CRX Manifest Format 1 and installed inline
2. New plugin build with CRX Manifest Format 2 and installed from Chrome Webstore

Problem:
Extension ID has changed, so installation is not treated as an upgrade. Instead, both plugins are installed after installing the second.

Details:
Because of the stricter plugin management in Chrome 21 and the move to the Extension Manifest Format 2, I'm converting a plugin which used to be installed in-line to one that's pulled from the Chrome webstore. But I've run into an issue - the plugin's ID was previously determined by  a field in the manifest JSON file and now it's auto-generated by the store and it's different. Because of this, my new version of the plugin isn't treated as an update and I end up with two versions of the plugin installed. Is there some way to prevent this behavior?

This scenario reminds me of a similar one in RPM installation which occurs when you change an RPM's name but still want to preserve its upgrade behavior. In this scenario, you can use either the "Provides" or "Obsoletes" fields. Does the CRX build process offer something similar? Basically I want to call out that plugin ID B is replacing plugin ID A.

Comment: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/packaging.html#upload

Answer (score 0):

The upload link Rob provided above works. Another approach is to use the uninstall function described at http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management.html. It allows you to delete based on ID.